# Best way to analyse categorical data?

Tags: python, categorical-data, exploratory-data-analysis

I'm fairly new to data science so forgive the newb question, but: what's the best way to work with categorical data when doing exploratory data analysis? Is there a dedicated field for that?

In this case I've got a set of Covid-19 patient data:

https://open.toronto.ca/dataset/covid-19-cases-in-toronto/

[image: Some of the fields]

Besides the obvious that there are only a couple of numerical fields, I'm wondering if there's a "best practice" for making some insights there? To check the value_counts for each column seems an obvious one, and make sure that the data are good by checking null values. I might check correlation between different columns but that doesn't work here. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
Matthew

Comment: I'm thinking that the best first step - since so many of these columns are yes/no - is to create dummy columns changing those to 0/1.

Comment: Rather than providing an opaque laundry list of variable names, it would be so much clearer and simpler if you were to include a sample of the data that goes with them, as in a spreadsheet. That said, contingency table analysis is commonly used wrt categorical information. Agresti's *Categorical Data Analysis* is the standard go-to text.

Comment: Good suggestion - I added a pic to hopefully clarify. I'll have a look at the Agresti text as well. Thanks!

Comment: I have to admit, I'm not a huge fan of the "Here's a data set. What insights can we gain?" approach. The vast majority of the time, you're better off asking your question first. What do you want to know? Then decide what data you need to answer the question. Then get the data. Then clean the data. Then process the data. Then answer your question, or decide you can't, yet. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: I hear you, but this isn't so much about solving real-world questions as it is about getting used to the tools and best practices of data analysis. If that's using data I find interesting, bonus.